# Is there something like "did you forget to attach a file" in Apple Mail?

Tags: email

In Thunderbird there is something like "are you sure you did not forget to attach a file" if you mentioned words such as "attached/in the attachment/ attach" and many more (could be set default on tb).

Is there something similar for the Apple mail on OS X 10.9 Mavericks or for iPhone (iOS 6)?

Answer (score 1):

For OS X, there is a beta version of an older free (donationware) plugin called [Attachment Scanner Plugin for Mail.app](http://eaganj.free.fr/code/mail-plugin/) that is compatible with OS X Lion and OS X Mountain Lion. It works similar to the one you have mentioned for Mozilla Thunderbird. Since OS X Mavericks was only recently released, you can test it to see if it works or contact the author.

On iOS though, there's nothing of this sort in the stock `Mail.app`. Due to `application sandboxing`, third party developers cannot develop plugins for any application (Apple's apps or otherwise). This can only be supported if Apple makes such a feature available in `Mail.app`. I do not know if third party mail apps have such a feature.