# MacMail Forgotten Attachents Reminder

Tags: mail.app, email

I am trying to find a solution/plugin to remind me about adding attachments to an email on MacMail (using OS X El Capitan). I tried the "just double check your email, you idiot" option to no avail.

There is a [deprecated plugin](http://eaganj.free.fr/code/mail-plugin/) and wanted to know if any alternatives have been developed, or if there's a new sneaky setting that might do this for me.

I also found [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106949/is-there-something-like-did-you-forgot-to-attach-a-file-in-mac-mail) but given that's 3+ years old I would like more up to date feedback, in the hope that Apple has opened a new door.

Anyone know of a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a Mail plugin which does what you're looking for called [Send Companion](http://www.dutchovate.com/) (free, with other paid features). As of the time I'm writing this, it purports to work with the latest versions of Mail.

Comment: From the Send Companion [website](http://www.dutchovate.com/products/sendcompanion/): "Currently Send Companion is not under active development, we support our current users but don’t sell any new licenses."

Answer (score 1):

[MailButler](https://www.mailbutler.io/) does this and much more for the Mac mail app.

I tested the attachment reminder feature in MacOS Sierra (10.12.1) and it worked perfectly:
[image: Screenshot of working attachment reminder]

They have a free version and two tiers of paid versions, though the free version has a lot of good features (including the attachment reminder):

- Undo Send
- Cloud Upload
- Attachment Reminder
- Avatar Images
- Direct Inbox
- Emojis
- Unsubscribe
- Inbox Pause
- Quote
- Giphy

Their website [mailbutler.io](https://www.mailbutler.io/) has descriptions of all the features.